# Interpretation of a regular expression

Tags: regex

I'm still am learning regular expressions and having trouble interpreting the following expression:

```
 (?<!\w)
```

Comment: You should go and read http://regex.info. This is a negative lookbehind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means match anything which has no word before it..

To see the effect use `(?<!\w).`

---

For Example

```
Hi World!
^  ^     ^
```

The words above `^` would match because there is no word before them

1]Why would H match?

Because `^`(start of string) is non word

2]Why would it match at end?

Because `!` is non word and so `$`(end of string) would match